# Does gsub! copy the string's buffer?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know exactly how a string object's internal string buffer is updated during a #gsub call in these two cases:

1. No substitution was performed. For example `"hello".gsub!('r', 'a')`.
2. The length in bytes of the search string and replacement string are exactly the same. For example, `"hello".gsub!('e', 'a')`.

In these two cases, will #gsub create a new string buffer, copy the original buffer to the new one, then throw away the original? Or will the substitution be done in-place?

Comment: Why does it matter? There are multiple implementations of Ruby, the answer probably depends on which implementation (and version) that you're interested in.

Comment: As @muistooshort said it depends on the implementation. You can check https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L4051 for latest MRI implementation.

Comment: MRI creates a new buffer and replaces the string. If no match was found, the string is left unchanged.

Comment: @Stefan: If you are certain of that then you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MRI has a single method [`str_gsub`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L4051) to handle both, `gsub` and `gsub!`, depending on the last parameter:

```
static VALUE str_gsub(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE str, int bang)
```

If no match is found the method just returns, either `nil` (`gsub!`) or a copy of the string (`gsub`):

```
beg = rb_reg_search(pat, str, 0, 0);
if (beg < 0) {
if (bang) return Qnil;  /* no match, no substitution */
return rb_str_dup(str);
}
```

Otherwise, a new string buffer is created:

```
dest = rb_str_buf_new(blen);
```

Then the substitutions are performed and afterwards the string is either replaced (`gsub!`) or the new instance is returned (`gsub`):

```
if (bang) {
    rb_str_shared_replace(str, dest);
}
else {
RBASIC(dest)->klass = rb_obj_class(str);
OBJ_INFECT(dest, str);
str = dest;
}
if (tainted) OBJ_TAINT(str);
return str;
```

Comment: Good explanation..I enjoyed.. :)